# Strange error running query using ejb3 /hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am having the following statement.

```
result = (BigDecimal)m_EntityManager.createNativeQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```

Query is:
     select sum(field5) from myTable where field1 = '?#This' and
     field2=1234 and field3 IN ('7183328608','7187931685','7187931686')

Hibernate version is: 3.2.1ga

When ran against development and QA servers, we are having no problem
However, when deploying to production, there is an exception/error is observed.

```
ERROR: [BillSessionEJB: ] Error in runSingleResultNativeQuery(): running query: 
select sum(field5) from myTable where field1 = '?#This' and   
 field2=1234 and field3 IN ('7183328608','7187931685','7187931686')
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not 
execute query javax.persistence.PersistenceException:    
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org .hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:629)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:99)
at com.broadview.billing.billingdataservices.beans.BillSessionEJB.runSingleResultNativeQuery(BillSession
```

Development and QA server are running SQLSERVER 2012, Production is running 2005.  Is there a difference?
My only thought is that to put a name for the column sum.

```
as 'Total' .. in select
```

Any comments, ?? Please share thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems ok. Are the column names correct? The documentation of SQLGrammarException hints that:

> Implementation of JDBCException indicating that the SQL sent to the database server was invalid (syntax error, invalid object references, etc).

So the syntax is just one of the possible culprits. Try to run your query by hand on production and see what the DB tells you.

Comment: 1.) The running query works OK in SQL Query analyzer
2.) Yes, the names are correct.  
3.) When I specified the name of a returned agregate value
    like "select sum(field5) AS 'total'..."
    it started to work in Productin BUT stopped workining in 
    development.  
It is not the first time, I am running into issues with hibernate .. when I inherit a project that started long time ago (not by me).. 
I wonder how people manage these things ?  We can't upgrade both servers at the same time..

Comment: @dimar It is always a problem when test configuration is different to production. And the only way around is to fix the differences. You should try to find a way to test against 2005. :)

Comment: @dimar Also it's hard to believe that your production wouldn;t accept `sum()` without `as`. Maybe a there is a difference in dependecies as well?